# Should training data be different from validation data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

So I have this cnn in python. My data has 1000 training images and 100 validation images for each class. However my validation images are the same with my training data just less. I'm facing some accuracy problems so could this be one of the reasons?

Comment: Of course they should be different.  This is a fundamental mistake.  I'm not sure what resources you are using to guide you in learning this, but this part of the basics.

Comment: @AirSquid Mostly self taught cause I have to do this project. Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: Fair enough.  If you are in an academic environment, you should have some resources that walk you through the steps & essentials.  If not, there are plenty of neural net tutorials out there as a reference (buyer beware... ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the validation data should be different (not a subset of) than the training data.
That's because the validation data is to validate that the model isn't overtrained to the training data... if it were a subset of the training data, that obviously won't work.